# Proving extended AM-GM inequality using a monotonic function

Tags: inequality, means

The [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) is a known one, it states that for *any list of n numbers*, the following is true:

$$ \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \text{...} + x_n}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot \text{...} \cdot x_n }$$

But there are other important statistic means in math, such as the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean):

$$ H =\left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^{-1}}{n}\right)^{-1}$$

Or the [root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square):

$$ X_\text{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} (x_1^2 + x_2 ^ 2 + ... + x_n^2)} $$

The AM-GM can be extended with these means. More specifically, given *any list of numbers*:

let A be the *arithmetic mean*, GM be the *geometric mean*

let H be the *harmonic mean* and $X_\text{rms}$ bet the *root mean square*

The following is true:

$$ X_\text{rms} \ge A \ge GM \ge H $$

All of these inequalities can be proven using [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), and it is a well-known proof. 
But I want to consider a different approach:

$ \text{For any list of n numbers, let's define the function }$

$$ S(p) = \left( \frac{x_1^p + x_2^p + \text{...} + x_n^p}{n} \right) ^ \frac{1}{p} $$

$ \text{Then} $ $ H = S(-1) $, $ A = S(1) $, $ X_\text{rms} = S(2)$

$ \text{Notice that}$  $GM = \lim_{p \to 0} S(p) $

So we can say for sure that $S(2) \ge S(1) \ge S(p \to 0) \ge S(-1) $.
We then make the hypothesis that $ S(x)  \text{is monotonically increasing on the set of real numbers }$

My question is how to prove this hypothesis? Ideally, your answer would also contain a proof of $\lim_{p \to 0} S(p) = GM$ as I figured this one out on pure intuition.

**P.S** I am in the last grade of school right now, so *no high-level* math (Higher than basics of calculus or complex numbers theory) would be *prefered*. Still, though, any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You should at least learn asymptotic expansion (see links from my profile), so that you can immediately confirm systematically yet rigorously your guess that the power mean tends to the geometric mean as the power tends to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is shown in many places.

There is a proof
using Jensen's inequality
 in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean

One book I like is in
chapter 8 of

THE CAUCHY–SCHWARZ
MASTER CLASS
An Introduction to the Art of
Mathematical Inequalities
by
J. MICHAEL STEELE

It's available in both
soft-cover and digital.

[https://www.amazon.com/Cauchy-Schwarz-Master-Class-Introduction-Mathematical-ebook-dp-B00KILLJLA/dp/B00KILLJLA/ref=mt_kindle?_encoding=UTF8&me=&qid=1569430702](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KILLJLA)

Other good references are
INEQUALITIES
BY
EDWIN F. BECKENBACH
AND
RICHARD BELLMAN

and
the classic 
Inequalities
by G. H. Hardy, J. E. Littlewood, G. Pólya

Comment: Are there any free online resources where I can see this proof? I think it would be strange to buy a mathematics book for only one proof...

Comment: I did a search for "generalized mean" and found the reference I added to my answer.